# Xcode 9.2 hanging issue for storyboard only

Tags: swift, xcode9.2

My Xcode 9.2 is hanging when ever tried to open Storyboard. I have tried reinstalling the Xcode 3-4 times but not working for me, hanging is only happens for storyboard. Other part is working fine.

Comment: are you having a good system configuration ? (ram/cpu..) 
also try to clean derived data

Comment: Yes 16 Gb Ram i3 processor, also tried to clean derived data, it loads storyboard and within 20-30 seconds it hanged up.

Comment: can you show post a video ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6h5uywa9hk6v40g/Xcode9%20StoryBoard%20Hang.mov?dl=0

Check it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the video you posted, the time seems normal. This is due to the fact that there is `a lot of info` that needs to be `loaded`.

What you can do is `split your story board into smaller ones`.

Just to double check if your xcode/machine works fine, you can create a new project and open the new storyboard. I imagine it will still take a few seconds but you will have a reference behaviour.

Comment: Xcode is working fine for other projects and also i create new storyboard , that is working fine for same project but how to make it possible to work with previous storyboard that is created in xcode 8, i have to make all screens compatible to iphone x so i upgrade it in xcode 9.

Comment: It is hanging continuously whenever trying to open it